# array in MYSQL query with OR statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have a where clause that is in an array, I am having a problem where i need service.active = 1 to also possible match 2,3 or 4.

I am not sure how to do this in an array.
So i wanted:

service.active = 1 OR service.active = 2 OR service.active 3 OR service.active = 4

at the moment i can only get it to work by 'service.active' => 1,

```
#Get the data
$services = get_services(array(
    'service.id' => $service_id, //Service we are trying to get
    'service.active' => 1, //Active services only
    'service.owner_id' => $userid, //Just to be sure another user isn't   trying to get a service that isn't theirs
));
```

Comment: Have an SQL statement like this?  SELECT * FROM service WHERE service.active IN (1,2,3,4);

Dont use OR it can cause problems and its a  bit slow.

I dont know if you are using a RAW SQL query or a PDO prepared statement to help further. But you can implode the array to get the list

Comment: Whoo thats what i was after, i was able to get it to work using the in satement. Thank you  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Daryl B in [this comment](//stackoverflow.com/questions/28891186/array-in-mysql-query-with-or-statements#comment46043399_28891186):

> Have an SQL statement like this? SELECT * FROM service WHERE service.active IN (1,2,3,4); Dont use OR it can cause problems and its a bit slow. I dont know if you are using a RAW SQL query or a PDO prepared statement to help further. But you can implode the array to get the list